# Reload the content of .cfg file in OSGi Karaf and Blueprint on each class use

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I am trying to inject some external data into a class using Karaf Blueprint DI, and OSGi Bundles.

The config file is located on etc/com.company.feature.config.cfg under Karaf home and it contains this parameter : `attr1=test1`

My goal is to use this parameter each time the object of MyClass is called or used. So the file is red. Note the file will not change during the run of Karaf.

My problem is that I can see the value in the console **after installing or updating my bundle**. After this, when the object of this class is called, the value is set to `null`

The blueprint configuration, OSGI-INF/blueprint/context.xml :

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"... >
     ...
     <!-- 
          The file is located on etc/com.company.feature.config.cfg under Karaf, 
          and it contains "attr1=test1" 
      -->
     <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.company.feature.config" update-strategy="reload">          
        <cm:default-properties>
           <cm:property name="attr1" value=""/>
        </cm:default-properties>
     </cm:property-placeholder>

     <bean id="my-bean" class="package.MyClass" init-method="init">
        <property name="attribute" value="${attr1}" />
     </bean>
</blueprint>
```

Java MyClass Class :

```
class MyClass {
    private String attribute;

    //getter and setter

    public MyClass(){
       init();
    }

    private void init(){
       System.out.println("data : " + attribute);
    }
}
```

Karaf Output :

```
karaf@root()> data : null
```

Answer (score 2):

You call init in the constructor. At this point the attribute is not yet set.
Remove this call and it should work.

Another probem might be that init is private. I am not sure if blueprint can call it as init-method.